# custom FXML component not loading - classnotfoundexception

Tags: java, javafx, controller, components, fxml

I have followed tutorials and created my own custom element.  It is an AnchorPane containing 6 overlapped canvases to create a graphing framework.
Below is the magnitudeGraph.fxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<fx:root type="javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="700.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/9" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">  
   <children>
      <Canvas fx:id="backgroundCanvas" height="300.0" width="900.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <Canvas fx:id="series1Canvas" height="300.0" width="900.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <Canvas fx:id="series2Canvas" height="300.0" width="900.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <Canvas fx:id="series3Canvas" height="300.0" layoutX="7.0" width="900.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <Canvas fx:id="series4Canvas" height="300.0" width="900.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
      <Canvas fx:id="savedSeriesCanvas" height="300.0" layoutY="-1.0" width="900.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0" />
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

Fairly Simple.  I then have a custom controller which loads this framework, called magnitudeGraphController

```
public class magnitudeGraphController extends AnchorPane implements Initializable  {
@FXML 
public Canvas backgroundCanvas;

@FXML
public Canvas series1Canvas;

@FXML
public Canvas series2Canvas;

@FXML
public Canvas series3Canvas;

@FXML
public Canvas series4Canvas;

@FXML
public Canvas savedSeriesCanvas;

public magnitudeGraphController(){
    System.out.println("Graph Initialised");
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("magnitudeGraph.fxml"));
    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try {

        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
```

Nice and easy. So then on my main application controller I can call an instance of magnitudeGraph and the controller will load the fxml file with the root element being the anchorPane.

This is called with the following method in the main app:

```
public magnitudeGraphController spectrumgraph = new magnitudeGraphController();
```

Now the difficult thing comes when writing the fxml for my main app.  I wrote the import for the controller:

```
<?import myApp.magnitudeGraphController?>  

<AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
    <children>
         <magnitudeGraphController fx:id="spectrumgraph" layoutX="38.0" layoutY="33.0" minHeight="200.0" minWidth="700.0" prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="944.0">  

</AnchorPane>
```

What I get is an error on the fxml editor stating 'Class javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane' does not support property MagnitudeGraphController'.

What is confusing me is that this was working perfectly.  All I have done is changed the name of the fxml file and controller to a more identifiable name and have refactored the file to reflect this. I have gone back through my archived backup of when this was working and cannot find any difference except the file names.  If I try and compile the error throws classnotfoundexception when trying to load magnitudeGraphController. 
I have been tearing my hair out for ages and cannot find what has brought the whole thing down.

Comment: `FXMLLoader` assumes type names start with uppercase letters. (Naming conventions agree with this btw.) However this wouldn't load anyways, since the `<children>` tag is never closed.

Comment: Thank you so much. I had the closed children tag in my code, just didn't copy it correctly onto here.  However I was not aware of the naming convention. Changing the controller to uppercase fixed this straight away.  I shall read up on naming conventions next and see if there's anything else I need to know.